# Prevent users from switching airplane mode and location service on or off

Tags: windows-10, administrator, cellular, airplane-mode

As a windows 10 administrator, how can I prevent non-administrator users from turning on airplane mode and turning off location services?

These tablets will be used by drivers (delivery) that needs to be tracked all the time. We don't want them to hide by turning off the location service or use airplane mode. Aside from that, the user should also not be able to turn off cellular. Is there something in gpedit that can handle those things?

These are Windows 10 pro with Fall creator's update.

Comment: If the drivers want to avoid being tracked, they could just wrap the tablet in aluminium foil. That will block all signals.

Comment: That's another problem we can deal with later. lol.

Comment: "These tablets will be used by divers" Are they waterproof tablets? I didn't think GPS worked underwater ... :)

Comment: Group Policies [`gpedit.msc`] would be used - for the ones required, you'll likely need to google them until an answer is posted.